# Varchar(10) or int for Status Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When creating a table which column type is better from a searching / speed standpoint?

For certain tables I run across a need for a column called `Status`. I typically store this an `int32` in the database and then use a class to reference it in my code:

```
 public static int Published = 1;
 public static int Draft = 0;
 public static int Deleted = -1;
```

Is there much of a speed difference in using this column as a `varchar` instead?

```
 public static string Published = "Published";
 public static string Draft = "Draft";
 public static string Deleted = "Deleted";
```

I like the second `varchar` method better because it helps with readability in the database and then I don't have to constantly convert the int status code to a string for human use.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What RDBMS. If you're using MySQL, you could use an `ENUM`. It's stored as an integer, but displayed as a string.

Comment: MS SQL and Entity Framework

Comment: Typically, `int` is better for performance, because **(1)** it's only 4 bytes long, and **(2)** it's a **fixed-width** data type that doesn't incur the overhead of a variable-length datatype (like `varchar`). `Varchar(10)` is between 2 and 12 bytes long, and variable-length, which is slightly less optimal for performance - it carries a bit of overhead with it. These points really only come into play if you have a substantial number of entries, though - if you have several hundreds, the performance difference is neglible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a best practice you should choose the narrowest column. The narrower the column, the less amount of data SQL Server has to store, and the faster SQL Server is able to read and write data. In addition, if any indexes are created on the column, index size will be narrower and hence the overall performance will be impacted on a positive side. 
As you have column that is designed to hold only numbers, use a numeric data type, such as `INTEGER`, instead of a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` data type. Numeric data types require less space to hold the same numeric value as does a character data type. This helps to reduce the size of the columns, and can boost performance when the columns is searched (WHERE clause), joined to another column, or sorted.

Also if you are going to store values in columns as numbers -1, 1 through 10, then the `TINYINT` data type is more appropriate that the `INT` data type.

Hope this helps!!